# while build my Flex project through Ant i got error that "not enough memory "

Tags: apache-flex

while build my Flex project through Ant i got error that "not enough memory " so how could i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

in your eclipse.ini file ( in the eclipse folder ) you can set the max memory used

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

it is default 256M  you can change it to whatever your machine can handle